# When do Protonmail filters run?

Tags: protonmail

I have a ProtonMail Pro account. I have created a number of filters in ProtonMail and it seems like they are not running consistently, but possibly I am wrong about this. My specific question is do the filters run on the server when emails are received, or when I open the webclient to check mail? Related to this, if I am using the Proton Mail bridge with Thunderbird will they work the same way as using the webclient?

If it makes a difference to use Sieve rules instead I could do that.